# not a single-group group function (00937. 00000)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT p.pdept.dno,
       MAX(SUM(p.budget)) AS max
FROM Proj111 p
GROUP BY p.pdept.dno
```

Although I have included all the necessary attributes in select statements to group by clause it will generate above issue? How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't nest aggregate functions like that.  If you want to get the maximum sum from each group, then you can try this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.pdept.dno AS dept,
           SUM(p.budget) AS budget
    FROM Proj111 p
    GROUP BY p.pdept.dno
)

SELECT t.dept,
       t.budget
FROM cte t
WHERE t.budget = (SELECT MAX(budget) FROM cte)
```

The common table expression which I have named `cte` finds the budgets for each department.  The query then restricts this result to the department with the maximum budget by again querying the `cte` for the maximum budget.

Comment: Then it says that the cte table does't exist.

Comment: Did you use the exact query I gave you?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  Your code have a little mistake, extra semicolon `;`   before  `SELECT`

Comment: @Surename I added that _after_ the OP complained that my answer didn't work.  There is something else going on in his setup.